# PHP compare strings with hyphen

Tags: php

I need to compare 2 strings without replacing anything.

```
$str1 = 'short-eared owl';
$str2 = 'short-eared owl';

if (strcmp($str1, $str2)===0) { do this and that …}
```

The problem here is the hyphen. Even both strings are equal, strcmp() does not result in 0 (equal). Why ?

How to compare those strings correct ?

UPDATE

Here is the essential piece of code

```
<?php
    $cat=$_GET["cat"];

    if (($handle = fopen($csvFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $dataArray = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";"); 
        while (($dataArray = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            for ($i=0; $i < 4 ; $i++) {
                if (strcmp($cat,$dataArray[$i])===0 ) {
                // do this and that
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

What I do is comparing $_GET var which is a string like 'short-eared owl'  against columns of a cvs file. If I found 'short-eared owl' in that file I return. But strcmp() does not work here because of the hyphen. If I delete the hypen manually for testing purposes strcmp() matches.

UDATE 2

When evaluating the strcmp() function at php site [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strcmp.php) there is an "Anonymous" User Contribute Note talking about `collation`. He writes :

> In summary, strcmp() does not necessarily use the ASCII code order of
>   each character like in the 'C' locale, but instead parse each string
>   to match language-specific character entities (such as 'ch' in
>   Spanish, or 'dz' in Czech), whose collation order is then compared.
>   When both character entities have the same collation order (such as
>   'ss' and '�' in German), they are compared relative to their code by
>   strcmp(), or considered equal by strcasecmp().

If this is the problem with the hyphen char how to solve it ?

Comment: They might look identical hyphens, but are they actually identical characters?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0dce066216d5ef7eb475428e842e90abb18ec907

Comment: $str2 is actually a copy of $str1. So I assume that they are also identical characters

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks for that link. Haven't seen that before. There the compare result is 0 (equal).  In my code it isn't. I have to dive deeper ... hmm

Comment: Are you defining the variables type for these 2 variables ? are both same type? because  === operator along with data also match that they should have same type

Comment: How about adding an actual use case for the issue, with some of the code around it that defines the variables being used. Clearly no problem with the snippet you posted, so you are not posting the right part.

Comment: @narenda Actually I compare a $_GET variable coming from an ajax call with a cell of a data array getting from php fgetcsv() . So I have to evaluate that I guess.

Comment: @MrMarlow. Well I wanted to make it simple. I will update the question in short.

Comment: @Ben - inside the for loop, what do you get if you output `var_dump($cat); var_dump($dataArray[$i]);` ? I am questioning if `$_GET['cat']` container a category `INT`, but $_GET is returning it as a string - depending on server config, that's not uncommon, so a compare against a string and an int would fail.

Comment: For example - this page has nothing but `<?php var_dump($_GET['id']);` in it. http://mrmarlow.co.uk/test2.php?id=1

Comment: @narendra Actually `strcmp` return value (which is always an int) is being compared to `0` so using the `===` operator is correct.

Comment: @MrMarlow - var_dump($cat) returns string(15) "short-eared owl".

Answer (score 0):

the code you wrote works fine i checked it myself like

```
$str1 = 'short-eared owl';
$str2 = 'short-eared owl';

if (strcmp($str1, $str2)===0) { 
    echo "success";

} else{
    echo 'fail';
}
```